# Hive query for row number

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on pyspark, need to write a query which reads data from hive table and returns a pyspark dataframe containing all the columns and row number.

This is what I tried :

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as rcd_num FROM schema_name.table_name
```

This query works fine in hive, but when I run it from a pyspark script it throws the following error:

```
Window function row_number() requires window to be ordered, please add ORDER BY clause. For example SELECT row_number()(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition ORDER BY window_ordering) from table;
```

Please suggest some solution.

Note: I do not wish to order the rows in any particular order, I just need row numbers for all the rows present in the table without any sorting or ordering.

Using spark 2.1

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()`might be required ordering so you can used `monotonicallyIncreasingId` function which gives you row numbers for all the rows present in the table.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonicallyIncreasingId

df.withColumn("rcd_num ", monotonicallyIncreasingId())
```

OR

`SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by (select NULL)) as rcd_num FROM schema_name.table_name`

you can set order by `select NULL`

Comment: From spark's documentation : "The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive." I need consecutive numbers.  Also the second solution you suggested throws this error: "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:39 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'NULL' ')' in expression specification." :(

Comment: can you try monotonically ? try once and check the rrsult.